# cannot convert 'int [2][4]' to 'int**' in assignment

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to do some stuff with pointers. I wrote the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int **p;

    int x[][4] = {{5,3,4,2},{5,3,4,2}} ;

    p = x;
    printf("%d\n", p);

    p++;
    printf("%d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting errors.
The error is at line :

> p = x;

I think I am confused with pointers. Please help me with it.

Comment: @user3528438: Wrong (and what do you mean with "padding"?). An array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`x` decays to type `int (*)[4]`. Hence use:

```
int (*p)[4];
```

Of course, change

```
printf("%d\n", p);
```

appropriately, such as:

```
printf("%d\n", p[0][0]);
```

**Update**

Given the declaration of `x`, you may use:

```
int (*p)[4] = x;
```

or

```
int* p[] = {x[0], x[1]};
```

But you may not use:

```
int** p = x;
```

Comment: can you pleas explain a bit more?

Comment: Depends which dimension OP wants to increment through. An alternative would be `int *p = &x[0][0]`.

Comment: @learner: Please understand SO is no tutorial or discussion site. There is "something" like `**p` (better: `int **`), but not here. Please do some research on your own about arrays and pointers. They are **not** the same!

Comment: can you please provide me some links?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made was the following: you knew you can handle arrays in a similar way as constant pointers, which also implies that pointers to pointers are similar to arrays of pointers, and which also implies that pointers to arrays are similar to arrays of arrays. However, arrays of pointers are different from arrays to arrays. "You only can play with the interpretation of the highest level of addressing."

This becomes more clear if you look at the size with which thing can be incremented (see below: 1. ~ 4. and 2. ~ 3. but not e.g. 1. ~ 2.).

From your question, the answer and reactions to the answer, I thought it would be appropriate to summarize all the weird syntax coming here together...

1. `int **p` is a pointer to a pointer of integers,

   which would look like `[address of int*]` in memory.

   p++ will move p by an amount sizeof(int *), which is the size of an hexadecimal number representing the memory location of a pointer to an integer.
2. `int (*x)[4]` is a pointer to an instance of int[4], i.e. a pointer to arrays of size 4 with integers.

   This would look like `[address of int[4]]` in memory.

   so x++ will move x by an amount of sizeof(&(int[4])), the amount of memory used to address an array of 4 integers
3. `int y[][4]` is an array of arrays of 4 integers each, so basically y[1] will points to the location to which y++ would points if you would have declared instead 'int (*y)[4]'.

   [ However, you cannot move around with "arraypointers" because they are implicitly declared as constant (int [] ~ int * const). ]

   It will looks like `[address of int[4]][address of int[4]][address of int[4]]...` in your memory.
4. `int *z[4]` is an array of pointers to integers

   so it will looks like `[address of int*][address of int*][address of int][address of int]` in memory. z[1] will give te value at the location z[0] + sizeof(int*).